# How to take an element with gtag?

Tags: html, twig, analytics, shopware, gtag.js

I'm setting up an `HTML.twig` page extension and I want to take a text from page body with `gtag`

This is for a shopware page

I've already tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
    'page_title' : 'homepage',
    'page_path': '/home'
});
```

but this code is alright: `gtag('config', 'Example');`

Instead of "Example" I want to take some text from the page body.

Comment: What do you mean by *"take some text from the page body"*?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if page.product.name %}
    gtag('product', '{{ page.product.name }}'); // for example :)
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You might want to do `{{- page.product.name | escape("js") -}}` in this case